# How can I clean up Symfony admin routes?

Tags: php, routes, symfony1

My backend URLs look like this:

```
 mysite.com/backend.php/blog
```

I'd like to change it to:

```
 mysite.com/backend/blog
```

Technically this isn't limited to admin apps, as Symfony grants every application two front controller scripts. But I hate having the script name in URLs and as such I'd like to change it. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

@codecowboy - I did resolve this by creating a 'backend' directory in the web directory. I then copied over the .htaccess file symfony puts in web, and I moved the backend.php and backend_dev.php front controllers to /backend and renamed them index.php and index_dev.php. Then within each front controller I tell PHP to look one directory further up for the project config class. I've been doing this for a while now and it serves my needs perfectly. I actually wrapped this all up in a task so that setting up a new admin app is a 1 step processs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add

```
 #I'm no regular expression expert or mod_rewrite expert, this line probably has some bugs 
 RewriteRule ^backend(.*)$ backend.php [QSA,L]
```

to your .htaccess file right before

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

and that solves 1/2 of your problem. Anything sent to yoursite.com/backend/xxx will be routed through backend.php. The other problem you get is with internal symfony routing. It will interpret yoursite.com/backend/xxx as a request for module "backend" and action "xxx". I'm sure it's not too hard to solve. Good Luck!